# Evaluate projects'/investments' impact on whole economy

Tags: macroeconomics, simulations, input-output

I have 200 ROI investment examples (projects) in a specific industry, say manufacturing of microprocessors. How and what methods can I use to evaluate the impact (GDP, added value, job growth, etc.) on a whole economy, say USA's, if a prime task is to show how such the investments positively affect the economy?